# GET file with correct name

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, rest

I'm working on a Word add-in with a form for selecting SharePoint Online documents, using the REST API.
At the moment, I was able to download the file directly by the URL [following this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
https://....com/sites/site/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/site/folder/Test.docx')/$value
```

However, this downloads the file with the name `$value` instead of the correct filename. Is it possible to get the actual name through REST?

Comment: Get any property using:_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/site/folder/Test.docx')/Title..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you download the file by the REST API, you just get the stream of the file even though you have downloaded the file.

https://....com/sites/site/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/site/folder/Test.docx')/$value

I suggest you could get the stream of the file by the REST API and save the file to the local with the correct file through the JavaScript code.

There is a similar post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451726/saving-binary-data-as-file-using-javascript-from-a-browser

More reference:

[Sending and Receiving Binary Data.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)

Comment: Although unwanted, this is what I had to end up doing. I wanted to avoid saving locally so that Word could use the auto-save to cloud feature, but oh well...